# Is Morrowind actually backwards compatible on Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, backwards-compatibility, the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

Elder Scrolls Morrowind is included in the Xbox 360 backwards compatible list, yet when I insert my Xbox Morrowind disk into my Xbox 360 (2008 Pro 60 GB HDD), I get this error "X 58085.0 B 1884.0" and it will not play.

I have read online that some people fixed this by hooking up to Xbox Live and updating their system, but some still could not play it even after all the necessary updates. I have never updated my 360 before, but does updating it even make it work? Or is something like [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12129) needed instead/in addition to updating?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the TL;DR of my confusing experience:

I connected my Xbox 360 online using an Ethernet cable:

1. to update the Dashboard to the latest 2019 version.
2. to then download backwards compatibility support when inserting an Original Xbox disk.

In my case, confusion was extended by the fact that my *Morrowind GOTY* disk would not provide the support download prompt even after updating my 360 Dashboard. It apparently took me to try the seemingly-unrelated *Star Wars: Knights of the Old Republic* Original Xbox disk to successfully receive and install the final backwards compatibility support enabling me to play *Morrowind GOTY* on Xbox 360!

I have no idea whether that was just a randomly achieved sequence of events unrelated to the choice of Original Xbox game used for the download prompt, but you could try the same and see if it helps.

I also don’t know if any of this process will become impossible by July 2024, when Xbox Live will be discontinued for Xbox 360.

My hardware:
Xbox 360 Elite 120GB HDD

Motherboard: (HDMI) Falcon - unknown version:
v1 Aug 2007 or v2 Aug 2008

You can find a YT video showing you how to identify your Xbox motherboard, if necessary.

I hope some of this was helpful

Answer (score 1):

Some original Xbox games are only compatible on the Xbox 360 with software updates. Your error code seems to indicate that your system does not have a recent enough update to play Morrowind. Updating normally via the internet should solve your issue.

The webpage you linked provides an alternate way to update your system if you cannot connect the Xbox 360 to the internet directly. However, that webpage does not provide a recent update. The page you linked contains an update from December 2007.

Comment: Do you have any personal experience with the update working for Morrowind? Or any links for additional information? I'm just asking because I have seen so much conflicting information online.